# Find header value for a cell in a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, header, grid, findcontrol

I have **gridview**, I want to do a foreach on it's rows and *get the value from column's header*  where there's a Label for one cell from this row.

```
foreach (GridViewRow mainRow in grid1.Rows)
{
    var header = mainRow.Cells[2].Parent.FindControl("LabelID");//is null
}
```

How do I find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value in RowDataBound event then you can check RowType like this

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
    Label header = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LabelID");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would access the **headerRow** and *enumerate through the according cells* (on *buttonClick* or on *RowDataBound* ...)

**default.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="headerLabel1" runat="server" Text="Headercolumn1"></asp:Label>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="itemLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnGetHeader" runat="server" Text="GetHeader" OnClick="btnGetHeader_Click" />
```

**default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnGetHeader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableCell headerCell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        // or access Controls with index 
        //     headerCell.Controls[INDEX]
        Label lblHeader = headerCell.FindControl("headerLabel1") as Label;
        if (lblHeader != null)
            Debug.WriteLine("lblHeader: " + lblHeader.Text);
    }
}
```